# My code is not Queuing as what I want

Tags: xcode

I have an app that build on Xcode, there is a button to logout the user and it contain the code below, I have no problem with it:

```
self.LbGoodBye.Text = @"Goodbye";

NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"myQasidaName=%@",[self.textUserName text]];
NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/MyWebSite/logOutUserDefaults.php"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300) {

NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:/MyWebSite/logOutUserDefaults.php?qasidaName=%@",[self.textUserName text]];
NSData *data =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
self.jasonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GoToMain" sender:self];
```

I have a label and I want to use it as a message to say Goodbye to the user, the problem is when I put the code at the begging, it does not work till the rest of code finished.

I am not sure if I have a problem with the Xcode, I tried to build new app but still have the same problem, I am using Xcode 6.0.1 and I started to build this app using Xcode 5.

I am new to Xcode and I do not have that much experience to sort out this problem.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did your code in main thread of the application thats why until its process is not completing it will not display label changes on screen.

use background thread for call logout web service. below is example of call api in background.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //Background Thread add your logout api call here
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GoToMain" sender:self]; add this code over here

    });
});
```